# Spring Cloud Api Gateway Cannot access to url of a service through api gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a problem about accessing any **url** through **Api gateway** in my **Spring Boot Microservices** example.

I can access any **url** through defined like **http://localhost:9000/api/v1/users/signup** (user service use port 9000)

When I try to access it like (**http://localhost:8600/userservice-api/api/v1/users/signup**) through api gateway, I get **404 Not Found** error message.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my **api gateway properties** shown below.

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=api-gateway

server.port=8600

## User Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/userservice-api/**

## Advertisement Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=advertisement-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://advertisement-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/advertisementservice-api/** 

## Management Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=management-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://management-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/managementservice-api/** 

## Report Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=report-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=lb://report-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/reportservice-api/**
```

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Edited 1st

```
## User Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/userservice-api/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/userservice-api/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
```

I tested it but it didn't work.

Comment: Because the url is not changed by default to `http://localhost:8600/userservice-api/api/v1/users/signup` is forwarding to `http://localhost:9000/userservice-api/api/v1/users/signup`. Use a filter to alter the url like `StripPrefix`, `SetPath` or `RewritePath`.

Comment: @spencergibb I cannot fix the issue. Can you help me?